# Does Grails use different localization messages based on domains?

Tags: grails, localization

I have the following `.properties` files in a new Grails 2.1.0 app:

```
messages.properties
messages_sv.properties
```

Will the values from `messages_sv.properties` be used when a user hits our `www.mysite.se` URL, or are the messages loaded based purely on the browser’s language settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages are resolved by locale independently of the URL. If you’d like to change the locale, take a look at the [the i18n documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/i18n.html#changingLocales) to get a better understanding of internationalization in Grails.